# Show event count for each resource and date based on selected date in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using full calendar scheduler .I need to show the event count for the **selected date** in front of the resources as a figure.Currently i am making the count from the controller and passing them to script and appending manually to the relevant resource.

This work fine but my problem that count is not based on **date**.I need to show the total count for the relevant date .

This is my output
[image]

This my my script

```html
 resources: employeeArr,
              resourceRender: function (info) {
               
                  var countLabel = document.createElement("span");
                  countLabel.style.backgroundColor = "#0b70cc";
                  countLabel.style.color = "white";
                  countLabel.style.padding = "5px";
                  countLabel.style.textAlign = "center";
                  countLabel.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
                  countLabel.style.lineHeight = "30px";
                  countLabel.style.borderRadius = "3px";
                  countLabel.style.marginLeft = "10px";

                  countLabel.innerHTML = " " + info.resource.extendedProps.Count + " ";
                  //var questionMark = '';
                 // questionMark += "<label for='HYDRO' style='background - color: #00B0F0 !important; width: 30px; height: 30px; color: white; text - align: center; vertical - align: middle; line - height: 30px; border - radius: 10px;'></label>"; /*+ info.resource.extendedProps.Count + " "  ;*/

                  if (info.resource.extendedProps.Count!=0) {
                      info.el.querySelector('.fc-cell-text')
                          .append(countLabel);
                  }

                 


              },
              events: eventsArr,
```

Is there any attribute in fullcalender to show the event count or any other method.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your description implies that the controller is not calculating the count based on the date. That would be the simplest solution. You can get the correct date information from fullCalendar and pass it to the controller, which can use it to count only events within the date range. This would require you to fetch the resources dynamically from an endpoint which provides the resources data in JSON format. See this page:  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-json-feed and read the section called "Fetching based on current date".